# Get string value of AfterProperties Look up Field

Tags: development, event-receivers

I'm having trouble getting the value of a look up field after a list item is submitted.

The XML for the look up field looks like this:

`<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Field ID="{6C798145-A205-4FC4-8175-837B0F7744CC}"
         Type="Lookup"
         SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"
         DisplayName="Work Project"
         Required="True"
         List="Lists/USNITWorkManagementProjectList"
         ShowField="ProjectName"
         UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="TRUE"
         Group="USNITWorkManagement"
         Name="WorkProject" />
</Elements>`

Both of these return null:

`properties.AfterProperties["WorkProject"].ToString()`

`properties.AfterProperties["ProjectName"].ToString()`

I'm new to this, so I'm sure I'm doing something simple wrong.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Since the fields are lookup types, use `SPFieldLookupValue` to get the value in the fields:

```
SPFieldLookupValue workProject = properties.AfterProperties["WorkProject"] as SPFieldLookupValue;
var workProjectValue = workProject.LookupValue
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm still getting a null error on workProject.LookupValue.  I tried "WorkProject" and the look up name "ProjectName", same result for both.   Any ideas?  Thanks again!

Comment: Check if the field contains any value using convert.tostring. Moreover, you need to use the internal name of the lookup field which is WorkProject

Comment: A value of a lookupfield in before/afterproperties is just a string. Only when you have the listitem you will get SPField like types.